# Cannot convert return expression of type 'ForumViewController' to return type 'UITableViewCell'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My code:

```
//
//  ForumViewController.swift
//  Kode4Kids
//
//  Created by Caleb Clegg on 17/06/2020.
//  Copyright © 2020 Group9. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ForumViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

    var tableView: UITableView!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .plain)
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "ForumViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ForumCell")
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    
    var layoutGuide:UILayoutGuide!
    
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *){
    layoutGuide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    } else {
        //fallback on previous versions
        layoutGuide = view.layoutMarginsGuide
    }
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.reloadData()
}






@IBAction func backTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as? HomeViewController
                   
                   self.view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
                   self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 12
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ForumCell", for: indexPath) as! ForumViewController
    
    return cell
}
```

}

[I keep getting: "Cannot convert return expression of type 'ForumViewController' to return type 'UITableViewCell', I've been at this for two days and my project is due for college next week. I'd really appreciate some help. "][1]

Any ideas on what might need to change?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dgxfn.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't cast `UITableViewCell` as `UIViewController`.
Replace this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ForumCell", for: indexPath) as! ForumViewController
    
    return cell
}
```

With this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ForumCell", for: indexPath) // since you're not doing any additional stuff here this would do
}
```

Note: If you've made a `xib` file for defining the layout of your `UITableViewCell` use it's class for downcasting. In your case `as! ForumViewCell`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return UITableViewCell not UIViewController in cellForRow function so replace the as ForumViewController  to “as ForumCell” or whatever the name of your custom UITableViewCell is.

Comment: Tried this but nothings changed. any other advice?

Comment: Can you show image what you have tried ? And your custom uitableviewcell class ?